# wget crashes on MacOS Big Sur 11.1 (M1 Apple Silicon)

Tags: macos, wget

I get the same result from a homebrew installed version of wget and also a locally compiled one.

when running wget it exits immediately with exit code 137

```
bash$ wget --help
Killed: 9
```

```
zsh$ wget --help
[1]    81709 killed     wget --help
```

I suspect something in the kernel is immediately killing the process with a SIGKILL

How could i check logs to see whats happening, or otherwise diagnose?

```
$ which wget
/opt/homebrew/bin/wget
```

```
$ brew info wget
wget: stable 1.20.3 (bottled), HEAD
Internet file retriever
https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/wget/1.20.3_2 (50 files, 4.0MB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2021-01-06 at 23:39:41
From: /opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/wget.rb
License: GPL-3.0-or-later
==> Dependencies
Build: pkg-config ✔
Required: libidn2 ✔, openssl@1.1 ✔
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Analytics
install: 126,729 (30 days), 315,648 (90 days), 1,235,170 (365 days)
install-on-request: 126,050 (30 days), 312,760 (90 days), 1,208,645 (365 days)
build-error: 0 (30 days)
```

```
$ file /opt/homebrew/bin/wget
/opt/homebrew/bin/wget: Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64
```

Comment: Please contact the Wget mailing list: bug-wget@gnu.org or drop by on IRC #wget on Freenode for more support. This is likely caused by the new hardware. We've not tested it on this hardware yet, so can't say what the problem is.

Comment: Can you show the output of `which wget` and maybe `brew info wget` and `file /opt/homebrew/bin/wget`?  My homebrew version works fine on my M1 Mac.  I'm using a poured bottle version, not compiled locally.

Comment: Thanks for that additional output.  Everything looks identical between our configs except the version # of wget.  Mine says `stable 1.21 (bottled), HEAD`.  Can you try to update to that version?  And to answer your original question, you can open the Console app to see the system logs, and maybe something in there will help too?

Comment: Turns out my homebrew installation was 'broken' or in a half-working state. After fully uninstalling and re-installing homebrew the wget install seems to be working fine. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out my homebrew installation was 'broken' or in a half-working state. After fully uninstalling and re-installing homebrew the wget install seems to be working fine.